# RUN chmod - error during docker build from dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to copy a .war file from my host desktop to a location inside my docker container. Then i want to extract this .war file and afterwards change the permission to all the files which lies under one of the extracted file folder. Thereafter i again want to rebuild a .war file (after deleting the old .war file) at same location that would ultimately contain the edited files with granted read/write permissions.This new .war file i can then copy under my tomcat/webapps folder inside docker to get deployed.

For this purpose i have written a docker file as shown

```
FROM tomcat:8.5-jdk11 
MAINTAINER derek

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/temp
COPY SP-files/WAR/SP.war  /usr/src/temp/
RUN jar -xvf /usr/src/temp/SP.war
RUN rm -rf SP.war
RUN chmod 777 /usr/src/temp/WEB-INF/native/*

RUN jar -cvf /usr/src/temp/SP.war .
RUN cp /usr/src/temp/SP.war  /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

During the docker build process i get the error 
 chmod: cannot access '/usr/src/temp/WEB-INF/native/*': No such file or directory

Indeed, my exploded SP.war has folder WEB-INF/native/{*all files to be edited are here*}.I have no clue why is it unable to locate the files under WEB-INF/native/    folder.
Is there some other way to specify the chmod command  in docker file ? I have also attaches a screenshot of error. [ERROR-IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEym1.png)
[Image showing -The folder WEB-INF/native/* is actually created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNtdo.png)

I have also tried using 
RUN /bin/bash -c chmod +x /usr/src/temp/WEB-INF/native/*  but no sucess..

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to run container to the point it works. A lot easier to debug.

Then run just:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5-jdk11 
MAINTAINER derek

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/temp
COPY SP-files/WAR/SP.war  /usr/src/temp/
RUN jar -xvf /usr/src/temp/SP.war
RUN rm -rf SP.war
```

After that run container and run command:

`ls /usr/src/temp/`

You'll have clear view of what's really going on with directory structure. After that, You may adjust paths to valid ones. Good luck!

Comment: The issue is that i could  not find anything except SP.war at the location where i run  RUN jar -xvf /usr/src/temp/SP.war command, Although i could see that SP.war gets inflated during this command run (i could see it on my docker terminal). Also, when i manually go to the location  /usr/src/temp/ and run   jar -xvf /usr/src/temp/SP.war command , i could see the exploded files appearing at that location along with SP.war. Does anybody have a clue why the exploded files not showing up after this docker file execution.

Comment: @AbhijotMann please check my edited answer. Should help. Please also post feedback how did You ended up.

Comment: @ instead, i tried to do it the way you suggested. But still i see only SP.war file  at location /usr/src/temp/

Comment: @ instead thanks for the help but i dont seem to find the cause for now atleast...